# How to open .dot using Open XML

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

I am trying to use Office Open XML to open a .dot file using WordprocessingDocument.Open() in C#

The code below works for .docx files but I ***have*** to be able to support .dot files

Since Open XML doesn't support dot files, how can I get the contents of a dot file into a docx file?

```
// Open Template
byte[] sourceBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(Template.FullName);

using (MemoryStream workingMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    // Load into memory
    workingMemoryStream.Write(sourceBytes, 0, sourceBytes.Length);

    using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(workingMemoryStream, true))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I'm getting the error "File contains corrupted data"

Answer (score 0):

Older `.DOT` files are in a binary format, not XML.  You'll need to use Word automation libraries or some other mechanism to open them; OpenXML does not support them.